# Save data from gridview with checkbox event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a Grid View in my web application with a column checkbox.
My problem is I can't use a button action for save the changes in that column because  clear the data in my gridview because the postback.

So how can I to save my changes in the grid?

Maybe catching cheked change?

this is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
```

And I fill it like this:

```
dt = obj.SelectByCustom(obj) 'this is my class
grd.DataSource = dt  
grd.DataBind()
```

Please Help.

Comment: Can I have full code of `asp:GridView`?

Comment: that is full code. The DataBinding full the grid automatically. So i don't define columns.

 <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" />
            <asp:Literal ID="liMsg" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="grdIncidencias" runat="server"   EnableModelValidation="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" >                                             
           </asp:GridView>
       </div>         
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem.

I used a UpdatePanel, putting my gridview inside.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP01" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
               <ContentTemplate>
                   <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" EnableModelValidation="True">
                   </asp:GridView>                       
               </ContentTemplate>

               <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnSave" EventName="Click" />                      
               </Triggers>

             </asp:UpdatePanel>
```